# Magento order created_at wrong date

Tags: magento, date, orders

I'm trying to get all orders in magento, from a specific user entered date.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $userdate));
```

But its not pulling out the correct orders.  If I use today's date, It pulls orders half from yesterday and half from today.

After a bit of Googling, it looks like there's two dates stored in Magento

```
$order->getCreatedAt()
```

Seems to give a UTC/GMT time

```
$order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()
```

Gives the same time as I see in the frontend (ie. my local timezone).

If I'm correct in what I have found, then how do I addAttributeToFilter using the CreatedAtStoreDate.  I have tried

```
('created_at_store_date', array('from' => $userdate)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::getIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

$formatStr = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$startStr  = 'Yesterday 12:00:00AM';
$endStr    = 'Yesterday 11:59:59PM';

$date   = Mage::getSingleton('core/date');
/* @var $date Mage_Core_Model_Date */

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

$collection->getSelect()
            ->where(
                sprintf("created_at BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",
                    $date->gmtDate($formatStr,$startStr),
                    $date->gmtDate($formatStr,$endStr)
                )
            );

$collection->load(true);
```

Comment: Is it recommended to send a query (not fully though) instead of using ORM? just curious about it.

Comment: +1 my from, to range on addAttributeToFilter was not fetching correct number of orders, this solved the issue. Thanks!